# Broken computer screen, unable to boot any OS

Tags: boot, laptop

First things first
I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD and i broke my screen.
I pluged a another screen in the HDMI port and it worked... but he start almost one time on one hundred,
during the periode of non working boot he just don't display anything on the other screen (HDMI),
i tryed during this time to press FN + all the fonction(exemple f12) key and nope that don't work,
sometime it do work but after rebooting... again it don't work,
also the fan work and the broken screen is entirly white when he don't wanna work

I tryed to put a another OS(Linux Mint Mate) on a another hardrive but again he work only some realy lucky time,

Also my screen is dead because he fall on the grond i don't think this is a material problem about the boot problem because sometime he start

So please if you have an awnser say it or if you need more information ask me if you wanna know i have a another pc if needed and also i'm french this is why i'm bad at english

I hope you have a great day

Comment: I am sorry but based on your description I would assume that the display is not the only part that is defect (e.g. a loose contact on the Mainboard). Complex hardware defects usually can't be solved "remotely", instead you need someone who opens the case and checks all the components for functionality. Therefore get the computer to a repair shop or a Lenovo service agent may be the best way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the help but do you have an idea why sometime he boot and sometime not?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities, a loos connection because of a broken soldering point, a very fine crack in the mainboard, partially broken cable. Modern digital chips internally base on analog electronics (as there is no such thing as digital voltage), therefore any sorts of oddities can happen when a component is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with my Acer laptop years ago, the screen stopped working after a crash.
I could display all information on the HDMI screen by simply removing the connection between the laptop and its screen. I opened it and unplugged the wire. Any HDMI connected was selected as the primary output on boot, just like it were the original screen.
Let me know if this works for you ^-^

Comment: The laptop doesn't boot most of the time. That's not just a broken screen.